# Wordpress, page 2 shows the same posts as page 1

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a premium that got its frontpage as a 'grid' .
Here's what it looked like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y392U.png

Then I installed a plugin named: Blog Layout by WebLumia Infomatics
to make my frontpage show up as a 'normal blog' and it now looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYBzG.png   which is perfect.

But when I click to page 2 to see more posts, it just shows the the same as on page 1.

I am not really sure what to change in the plugin code but I'm hoping some guys here could help me. I already have an idea where the change has to be made but I'm not sure at all.

Here's what some of the code looks like:

```
    switch( $this->type ) {
    case 'multipart':
        // Multipart page
        $posts_per_page = 1;
        $paged = max( 1, absint( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) );
        $total_pages = max( 1, $numpages );
        break;
    case 'users':
        // WP_User_Query
        $posts_per_page = $query->query_vars['number'];
        $paged = max( 1, floor( $query->query_vars['offset'] / $posts_per_page ) + 1 );
        $total_pages = max( 1, ceil( $query->total_users / $posts_per_page ) );
        break;
    default:
        // WP_Query
        $posts_per_page = intval( $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) );
        $paged = max( 1, absint( $query->get( 'paged' ) ) );
        $total_pages = max( 1, absint( $query->max_num_pages ) );
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a query_posts() call on that specific page template, you'll need to add the **paged** parameter to the query_posts() function, like:

```
$paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
query_posts('your_previous_parameters&paged=' . $paged);
```